# click event not working in ionic 4 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have declared one static variable which is holding 1 html code which contains one click event. On the click event I am trying to call a method which will open link inappbrowser. I am already using one pipe in order to display the msg in order to bypass the inbuilt security provided by angular. In the browser console no error is showing up but still i am not able to click the anchor tag that contains the click event.

**messages-notifications.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages-notifications',
  templateUrl: './messages-notifications.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages-notifications.page.scss'],
})
export class MessagesNotificationsPage implements OnInit {

  myMsg = '';

  constructor() {
      this.myMsg = '<u><a (click)="openBrowserWindow("https://stackoverflow.com")">click here</a></u>';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openBrowserWindow(text): void {  
    console.log("openBrowser called");     
    let browser = new InAppBrowser();
    browser.create(text, '_blank', 'location=yes')
  }
}
```

**messages-notifications.page.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item [innerHtml]="myMsg | safeHtml" class="ion-text-wrap"></ion-item>
  </ion-card>
<ion-content>
```

**safe-html.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }

}
```

[image: snapshot from the browser]

Comment: Angular doesn't parse and doesn't apply binding on your html

Comment: How to achieve this then? for my situation myMsg value is coming backend service which contains anchor tag and i need to open the link in device default browser once android build or ios build is created.

Comment: On your <ion-item> , add click event  ```<ion-item (click)="openBrowserWindow("https:/....")"></ion-item>```

Comment: still the same. not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `(tap)` instead of `(click)`?